# Transfering database from local server to remote webserver?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I do have lots of data stored in my local server in MySQL database and I want to transfer the same to newly purchased server. this server comes with PHP mySQl installation so how can I transfer the data and later say after 1 month update the whole data with new data. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you running on a server here you have access to shell (root or other privileged user)?

Comment: To better answer your question please provide the following information:
1) What version of MySQL are you using on source and destination?
2) Do you have shell access or are you using something similar to phpMyAdmin?
3) Please explain why you're wanting to wait a month to restore the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a binary backup from your local MySQL database server, copy the backup file to your newly purchased server, and restore the backup file.  Repeat this in one month with your new data.

You didn't specify what version of MySQL you are using, but other database backup methods from MySQL 5.1 can be found here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve information from your local server and - via AJAX protocol - send it to the new server's url.
Example: 
Your localhost server:

```
//local_host/localdatabaseconection.php
```

... retrieve data in xml format

jquery ajax SQL to new server:

```
 $.get("http://new_server_url.php", {get xml data as JSON notation }, function(result){
    $("div").html(result);
  }
```

The trick is to set the right url address. You can even set real-time backups between two different servers. Hope it helps, bye.

Comment: What service is this? its native to phpMyAdmin? could you explain a little bit more about it?